# MongoDB - How to find a doc by Id and find the docs that matches with an array of ids

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the following problem, i have many documents following this structure in my collection

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5c6ec80df2f9d02d08ce6b3c"),
"id": "0", 
"name": "first",
"details": "these are the details of each doc",
"relatedDocsIds": ["1","2"]
}
```

The "id" parameter is not repeated in the collection.

I want to get the complete documents with the ids that have relatedDocsIds.

I give the "id" of the doc from whom i want to get the complete related Doc from the array of ids.

So in this example, i want to get the related documents of the document with "0", the id of his related documents are stored in the array "relatedDocsIds".

How would be that query?

Im in a nodejs backend and i need that the response be the json containing the documents of that query.

Answer (score 0):

you should use mongodb `aggregate` for that, in conjuction with the `$unwind` and `$lookup` operator.

$unwind Deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a document for each element.

$lookup Performs a left outer join to an unsharded collection in the same database to filter in documents from the “joined” collection for processing.

here's the final query:

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$relatedDocsIds"
  },
  {
   $lookup:{
       from: "yourCollection",
       localField: "relatedDocsIds",
       foreignField: "id",
       as: "relatedDocs"
    }
  }
])
```

In mongoose you can do it like this:

```
Model.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$relatedDocsIds"
  },
  {
   $lookup:{
       from: "yourCollection",
       localField: "relatedDocsIds",
       foreignField: "id",
       as: "relatedDocs"
    }
  }
]).exec((err, docs) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(docs);
});
```

I would recommend going against this approach, because mongoose has a populate method, which will allow you to do this exact thing and their benchmarks suggest it's faster than the mongodb aggregate.

Comment: Hi! Tanks for your answer, which is that method? how would you do this?

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way I think it's using MongoDB Query Arrays operators

[MongoDB Query Arrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/)

[MongoDB $in operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

Example:

```
getCollection('collectionName').find({
  relatedDocsIds: {
    $in: ['0']
  }
})
```